# Why my httpcontext.cache works in localhost not production?

Tags: asp.net

I am using HttpContext.Cache.Insert to cache my data but it only works in my localhost.

In production, the cache just worked when I refreshed the same page, once I clicked to next page, my previous cache gone. Would this because of the production server web farm issue? Which it does not able to sync the cache data.

Answer (score 2):

If you're deploying to a farm you'll want a distributed cache, e.g. [memcached](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/). The built-in ASP.NET cache works in-process, without any syncing to other instances.

Comment: Mauricio Scheffer : +1 for the quick catch

Comment: @mourico , but it should work if it has multiple servers and load balaced properly right.

Answer (score 2):

Caching using the `HttpContext.Cache` is scoped at the app domain level, so if you're running in a web farm this kind of behavior would be expected.

Comment: @ataddeni : +1  for the quick catch